# How can I snapshot a VM before booting it for the first time?

Tags: virtual-machine, parallels, snapshot

I'm running MS trial VM images which are time limited, based on initial boot. MS recommend you store a copy of the downloaded image or take a snapshot before booting:
[image]

But how can you snapshot a VM without ever running it? I'm working via Parallels, but I'm not sure how relevant that is.

Answer (score 3):

Parallels can only snapshot a running VM. See https://kb.parallels.com/5691
I don't know whether you could run the VM without the Windows installation recognising that as its 'first launch' date or whether that would survive so long as you don't run through the entire setup procedure.

If you want to preserve the exact state before first run, I'd just duplicate the VM file itself, before first launch. That's going to take up disk space, of course, but is guaranteed 'safe'.

Of course, once you've duplicated the initial file, you then always have a spare you can experiment with, as regards Windows' 'first run' criteria & if you can get a snapshot early enough to not trigger it.